# creating a cache efficient version of a loop

Tags: c, loops, caching

I am trying to create a cache efficient version of a nested loop. The length of the loop is such that the data associated with the loop will be bigger than the cache size. I want to be able to iterate the loops in blocks so that it uses the cache more efficiently, but I don't know is this is possible.

I have tried a conventional blocking approach, but clearly this is not the correct solution for the loops as they stand, as j starts its iteration each time from 0.

```
#define N     65536
#define BLOCK 4096

int min(int a, int b);

int main() {

  double a[N];
  double d_a;
  int i,j;
  int bbegin; 
  int bend;

  for(bbegin = 0;bbegin < N;bbegin += BLOCK) {

    bend = min(bbegin + BLOCK, N);

    for(i=bbegin;i<bend;i++){
      for(j=0;j<i;j++){

        /* array a has been filled up elsewhere */
        d_a = a[i] - a[j];
        /* do some stuff with d_a */

      }
    }
  }

}

inline int min(int a, int b) { return (a < b) ? a : b; }
```

Comment: For me, `gcc 8.3.1` produces `xorl %eax, %eax; ret` for `main()`, I'm not sure how you expect to improve on this.

Comment: Sorry - I been really stupid here and not posted the correct middle to the loop.

Comment: What is the cache size? How much data is used in “do some stuff with d_a”?

Comment: Cache is 32k, 64 B, 8-way associative. Some calculations are made using d_a, and the result out into another size N array indexed by i.

Comment: Your `BLOCK` is too big. While processing a block, you will have a block of `a` indexed by `i` in cache, and that is 4096 elements of 8 bytes each (presuming `double` is 8 bytes), which fills your cache. You will also have a block of results also indexed by `i`, so that is another 4096 elements presumably of 8 bytes each. And you will have `a[j]` and some miscellaneous data. So your `BLOCK` needs to be less than half its current size.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for (i = bbegin; i < bend; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

to:

```
for (j = 0; j < bend-1; j++)
    for (i = max(bbegin, j+1); i < bend; i++)
```

This processes the same elements but in a different order, with the consequence
that every `a[i]` in the block will be recently used when the next `a[j]` is
loaded, so the elements in that block will remain in cache.

(`max` of course has the obvious definition, analogous to the `min` show.)

Comment: Thanks for your help!